# Clang -Wconditional-uninitialized on struct member array assignment

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings

I've run into some unusual behavior involving Clang `-Wconditional-uninitialized`.  Consider the following example:

```
typedef struct { int x[1]; } test_t;
test_t foo(void);
test_t foo() {
    test_t t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) t.x[i] = 0;
    return t;
}
int main() { }
```

Compiling with, e.g.

```
clang -o test -Weverything test.c
```

gives the following warnings:

```
test.c:6:12: warning: variable 't' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    return t;
           ^
test.c:4:5: note: variable 't' is declared here
    test_t t;
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

However, switching the line:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) t.x[i] = 0;
```

with

```
    t.x[0] = 0;
```

yields no warnings.  Note that it is sufficient to use `-Wconditional-uninitialized` and not necessary to pass `-Weverything`.  The `-O3` optimized assembly from both cases is identical, with a single `xorl %eax, %eax` emitted in both cases.  This is the minimum example I could create that showed this behavior.

I take some of Clang's `-Weverything` output with a grain of salt, but this seems to me like a bug and I'm rather confused.  Is there some kind of  undefined behavior I'm invoking that's causing this, or is this a false positive?  Is it in general a good or bad idea to keep `-Wconditional-uninitialized` enabled?  I see the same behavior on Clang 3.8.1 on Linux and (Apple) 9.1.0 on macOS.

Comment: The warning is unnecessary here, but understandable. The compiler can't be expected to know the loop condition at compile time to check if the variable is accessed at al, just consider the many possible ways to write such a loop. If you only want to clear the array and setup the `struct`, an initialiser like { {0} } would be the easier and more clear way. Sidenote: passing `struct`s is pretty uncommon in C (at least for non-trivial `struct`s like two scalars), as the language is completely pass-by-value, i.e. the whole data is copied everywhere. Cannonical is to pass pointers to the objects.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite The example here is intentionally extremely simple.  It is still unclear to me how the compiler can't figure out the outcome of a loop with a constant, well-defined number of iterations.  The same happens for more than 1 element.  If the structure is passed into `foo()` as a pointer and modified instead of getting created and returned, there is no warning as one might expect.  I know that is the typical way but I thought the above setup should still be valid, which is why the behavior is odd to me.

Comment: This is just a bug and should be reported as such.

Comment: Because a compiler is not an interpreter. To understand why the compiler does not figure this out, you should learn how compilers work and how they actually figure out when a variable is initialised. If you are sure the code is correct you can disable the warning around these lines or for this function. You might also have overread the "**may be**" part of the warning. For more read the following comment, too.

Comment: And @R.., It's not a bug. Spurious warnings like that can happen, because the compiler can't figure out all possible situations something is initialised. A compiler is not a static code analyser and even those can't test all sutuations. If you have a solution for the Halting Problem, you should spread it. Fame is wating for you. In fact those warnings are a goodie, the compiler is not required to warn about uninitialised variables.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: This is not a "solve the halting problem" case. It's a flat function with no branches. If the warning option gives false positives for such a trivial case, it's not a very useful warning option.

Comment: @R..: What do you think the `for` statement is? It's very well a halting problem, although this one is simple for a human, but it's just too much effort to catch that specific case if there are other common variants which can be missed easily. And from the compiler's view it's **not** trivial. Trivial are `if` constructs with simple assignments. I'd recommend a bit practicing compiler construction, namely the code analysis and loop unrolling part could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As @R.. suggested above in the comments, I've reported this as [LLVM bug 38856](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38856).  Apparently, according to them:

> -Wconditional-uninitialized is expected to have false positives: it warns in cases where a simple control flow analysis cannot prove that a variable was written to prior to each use. It is not field-sensitive nor data flow sensitive, so it cannot tell the difference between writing to one array element and writing to the whole array, and doesn't know that the loop actually always executes at least once.
>
> -Winitialized, by contrast, only warns when we can prove your program has a bug (or contains dead code).
>
> There are a few improvements we could make to reduce the false positive rate here (some crude field sensitivity might be relatively straightforward to add), but we don't want to recreate the full intelligence of the clang static analyser here, and keeping this warning simple enough that we can run it as part of normal compilations is a goal.

I also noted in that report that the following example gives no warnings even though one of the array members is clearly uninitialized:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int x[2]; } test_t;

test_t foo_3(void);

test_t foo_3() {
    test_t t;
    t.x[0] = 0;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    test_t t;

    t = foo_3();
    printf("%i %i\n", t.x[0], t.x[1]);
}
```

Which got me the reply:

> As I mentioned in comment#1, the analysis we currently perform cannot tell the difference between writing to one array element and writing to the whole array. In simple cases, this should be relatively straightforward to improve, so I think for that reason this bug is valid (but of low priority, given that this warning is expected to have false positives).

So `-Wconditional-uninitialized` is known for giving false positives.  Apparently the static analyzer isn't as thorough as I would have expected.  I'm surprised I hadn't run into anything like this before given more complicated scenarios where the analyzer seemed to have worked better, but as @toohonestforthissite also notes in the comments above, passing arrays around by value via structs like this is not a standard thing to do in C.

`-Wno-conditional-uninitialized` or `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wconditional-uninitialized"` should silence that warning for those who want to use `-Weverything` in a case like this.